# Why does this JavaScript code print the function code instead of returning a value

Tags: javascript

```
               const func = x => x * 100;
               const works = () => func(10) + func(10);
               console.log(works);
```

When I console.log, I should get 2000, but instead I get () => func(10) + func(10). Why is this?

Comment: `works` is a function, you should call it instead of just referring it, similarly you've called `func`.

Comment: It's because you are not invoking the function. You need to call the function in order to get the result. `console.log(works())`

Answer (score 1):

You should do that like this

```
const func = x => x * 100;
const works = () => func(10) + func(10);
console.log(works());
```

As `() =>` notation is arrow function and it be treated just like a function, so you have to call it with `()` to make it work.

*Please understand some basics of any Programming Language structs like `arrow functions in Javascript` before just posting the question here.*